# Replicate formula in cells with some adjustements

Tags: excel, formula

I'm making a big tab, and I have the following formula in my C2 cell :

```
=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(Data!A1:A20000;B2));"x";"")
```

I'd like to replicate this formula to other cells, copying it to C3 transforms it into :

```
=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(Data!A2:A20001;B3));"x";"")
```

As you can see, the range is also increasing - I'd like to "freeze it", and only have have a replica that would look like, for C2 to C6 for example :

```
=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(Data!A1:A20000;B2));"x";"") 
=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(Data!A1:A20000;B3));"x";"") 
=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(Data!A1:A20000;B4));"x";"") 
=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(Data!A1:A20000;B5));"x";"") 
=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(Data!A1:A20000;B6));"x";"")
```

And so on.. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "A1" referencing in Excel allows you to "lock" the references to a column (or row) by placing a $ sign before the column letter (or row number).

With a $A column reference in a formula, you can copy it to the right and it will always refer to column A.  Similarly with rows, A$1 will always refer to row 1 when you drag it down.

$A$1 will always refer to A1 if you copy it right or down.

This also applies to range addresses so Data!$A$1:$A$20000 will always refer to A1:A20000 whether you copy it down or to the right.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks a lot for the tip ! Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Lock the cells.

The formula in cell C2 should be 
    `=IF(MIN(COUNTIF(Data!$A$1:$A$20000;B2));"x";"")`